# DoFn process return type

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In Beam 2.3.0, the `DoFn` process API needed to return a generator through `yield` while in Beam 2.4.0, returning an object like dictionary from the process API works fine.

Is there a change in programming model from 2.3.0 to 2.4.0 ? For large scale Google Cloud Dataflow processing, is `yield` (generator) preferred over returning objects (list, dict) from the DoFn process API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to return an iterable. So if you return a dictionary, the output will really be the list of its keys. I stick with only using yield for simplicity.

Comment: I am not sure why they took out the assert on iterable check in 2.4.0...it can confuse new users...

Comment: Honestly, I can talk all day about the shortcomings of apache-beam's python sdk :)

Comment: `process` function function must return an `Iterable`. Returning a list clearly satisfies this requirement. Yielding stuff from `process` makes it a generator, which means that it returns an `Iterator`. In python, `Iterator` is also an `Iterable`, so this also satisfies the requirement.

Incidentally, unlike in `beam.Create()`, there is no check against returning a string as an `Iterable`. So you can run into bugs where the code iterates through your string when you didn't expect it.